# How can I do a type-level flip of `(,)`?

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I wanted to extend the idea of `fst` and `snd` to type classes.  So I wrote the typeclasses

```
class Fstable f where
   fst' :: f a -> a

class Sndable f where
   snd' :: f a -> a
```

It was easy enough to write the instance for `Sndable`, just the following

```
instance Sndable ((,) a) where
  snd' (a, b) = b
```

However the instance for `Fstable` is not as easy.  Now I would very much like to use a `flip` on `(,)` to create the `* -> *` I want.  But there is no flip at the type level so I would have to make my own or make the `* -> *` I want on my own.

I haven't done anything type level in a couple months but I remember that one way to make type level functions is using `FunctionalDependencies`.  I can make the flip of `(,)` easily enough:

```
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClases, FunctionalDependcies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class BackTuple a b c | a b -> c

instance BackTuple a b (b, a)
```

But `BackTuple` has kind `* -> * -> * -> Constraint` rather than the `* -> * -> *` I want.

So then I tried using a type synonym

```
{-# Language TypeSynonymInstances #-}

type W a b = (b, a)

instance Fstable (W a) where
  fst' (a, b) = a
```

But I can't curry so `W a` complains about the fact that it is not `W` is being supplied the wrong number of arguments.  I feel like maybe a type family could fix this but I don't know where to start.

I tried to build a flip, but I didn't really know how to start there either.

How can I make the flip of `(,)`?

Comment: Why not just change the `fst'` definition to `f a b -> a`? Then you can do `instance Fstable (,)`

Comment: We can't define instances on type synonyms or type families, since they are not injective in general, and injectivity is needed during type inference to keep inference decidable. We either need a newtype wrapper, or to work around the need to "flip" the type constructor in another way.

Comment: @4castle I could do that but If we wish to use `fst'` on things other than something that looks like a tuple I'd still have to solve this same problem.  Really it is just changes the problem statement so that I can solve this particular instance without any help to the general case.

Comment: What kind of things other than tuples do you want to use it on? This will help determine what the best solution would be.

Comment: Maybe you want something like [`Sel1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Tuple-Select.html#t:Sel1)?

Comment: I'd like to use this on a lot of types, not just tuples.  Of course many of these types will be isomorphic to tuples but some like `Either`, won't be.

Comment: It sounds like `Sel1` will give you the kind of solution you need. (Btw, `Either` wouldn't make a good instance of `Fstable` or `Sndable` because it might not have the value being requested)

Comment: @4castle I don't want `Sel1`, I really just want to solve this particular issue.  It's true I can't make `Either` an instance of `Fstable` by itself, I'd be doing something like `fst' :: (Monoid a) => Either a b -> a`.

Comment: I think you want a type family, not a type class (which is what introduces the `Constraint` to the kind).

Comment: If you don't want to use `Sel1` you can still copy its definition `class Fstable a b | a -> b where fst' :: a->b`, or use type families for computing `b` from `a`. Then, you can write the instances to fit your needs.

Comment: You can make new (non-tuple) instances of `Sel1` if that helps. If not, you might have to give some more details about the problem you’re trying to solve. If the question is *only* “how can I flip the type level `(,)` without using any sort of wrapper”, I would say the answer is you can’t. If there’s a bigger context to this problem, we might be able to help more though.

Comment: @DavidYoung This is about the broadest context of the problem.  I am just interested in trying to build this type class as is.  If the answer is I can't then that's ok.

Answer (score 5):

One choice would be to use a plain old simply-kinded class rather than a higher-kinded one. For example:

```
class Fstable tuple fst | tuple -> fst where fst' :: tuple -> fst
class Sndable tuple snd | tuple -> snd where snd' :: tuple -> snd

instance Fstable (a,b) a where fst' = fst
instance Sndable (a,b) b where snd' = snd
```

Analogous definitions can be done with type families if you prefer, of course:

```
class Fstable tuple where type Fst tuple; fst' :: tuple -> Fst tuple
class Sndable tuple where type Snd tuple; snd' :: tuple -> Snd tuple

instance Fstable (a,b) where type Fst (a,b) = a; fst' = fst
instance Sndable (a,b) where type Snd (a,b) = b; snd' = snd
```

The other choice, which is compatible with your original class, is to use a newtype to flip the arguments. Unlike a type alias, newtypes are suitable for partial application and so can be used with higher-kinded classes. The price you pay for this feature is the syntactic noise of introducing a newtype wrapper at each usage of the class.

```
newtype Flip f b a = Flip (f a b)
instance Fstable (Flip (,) b) where
    fst' (Flip (a,b)) = a
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that [`Flip` is provided by *bifunctors*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.5.3/docs/Data-Bifunctor-Flip.html).

Comment: @duplode Sure, and `Fstable` and `Sndable` as in the first choice here are provided by [`Sel1` and `Sel2` from *tuple*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Tuple-Select.html#t:Sel1).